# Cant import package in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I want to use this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-json-viewer in my vue3 project.

**Main.vue*

```
<json-viewer :value="Data"></json-viewer>

<script>
import JsonViewer from 'vue-json-viewer'
import vue from 'Vue'
...
components:{JsonViewer}
```

Comment: What's the error here? Also it should be `import Vue from 'vue'`

Comment: What is the error you're getting? And if this is not a CLI-scaffolded project (Going by the name 'Main.vue') are you using a custom webpack configuration?

Comment: Yea my bad, I did use import  `Vue from 'vue'`, the name of my fine is `storage.vue` 
i get this error 
`vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_34__.default is undefined
    <anonymous> storage.vue:122`

Comment: have you tried this one: https://github.com/qiuquanwu/vue3-json-viewer? Source: https://github.com/chenfengjw163/vue-json-viewer/issues/57#issuecomment-768482716